# make new image-request on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I want to make a request to get a new random image from unsplash [link.](https://source.unsplash.com/random/)
I'm not sure if this is the right way, however the concept is whenever the user clicks the button the background image should change. This is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var changeImg= function(obj){
        var imageSrc = 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/';
        $('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageSrc + ')');
    };
    $('#getImg').on("click", changeImg);
}
```

Currently the image changes only when the page is refreshed. How to make it change every time the `#getImg` button is clicked? Do i need Ajax to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's happens because browser already has loaded this resource. You should change URL to load new background image.

Try something like this:

```
var imageSrc = 'https://source.unsplash.com/random/?n=' + Math.random();
```